# Is there any problem using "break" inside a MPI process?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm doing the classical "ping-pong" program in multiprocess using MPI, and when I use `break` to exit from a `while` loop, the program never terminates. When I use other ways to exit the loop, the program ends normally. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

using namespace std;
#define SL cout<<endl
#define LIMITE_PINPON 10

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    SL;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int TP; MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &TP);
    int NP; MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NP);

    int cuenta_pinpon = 0;
    int NP_prev = (NP - 1 + TP) % TP;
    int NP_post = (NP + 1) % TP;


    if(NP==0)
    {
        printf ( "Proc. %i -> proc. %i: \t'Toma %i'\n", NP, NP_post, cuenta_pinpon );
        MPI_Send ( &cuenta_pinpon, 1, MPI_INT, NP_post, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }

    while (1)
    //while (cuenta_pinpon < LIMITE_PINPON)
    {
        MPI_Recv ( &cuenta_pinpon, 1, MPI_INT, NP_prev, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                   MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );

        cuenta_pinpon++;

        if (cuenta_pinpon > LIMITE_PINPON) break;
        
        printf ( "Proc. %i -> proc. %i: \t'Toma %i'\n", NP, NP_post, cuenta_pinpon );
        MPI_Send ( &cuenta_pinpon, 1, MPI_INT, NP_post, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    }

    cout << "Chau"; SL;SL;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I have to use Ctrl+C to end the execution:

[image: output]

Is the `break` instruction the problem? or which one is?

Comment: The problem isn't the `break` operator itself. You have to put it before the receive call. Otherwise, it breaks before the send calls and some receive calls will never receive their messages and simply block forever.

Comment: You defined a classical "ping-pong" handshake, then 'break' jumps out of the protocol.   Does the other task get informed that the ping-pong protocol has been aborted?  So, how would the other ask know to exit / terminate / do what you need?

Comment: I should have realized why "chau" was written just once... Thanks @HristoIliev! Thanks @2785528!